# onNewIntent() vs onReceive()

Tags: android, android-studio

Is `onNewIntent()` in the Activity is equivalent to `onReceive()`  in the Broadcast Receiver and can replace it? if not what the difference between the two ? and does the `onNewIntent()` still launch when the Activity is Paused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1.Is *onNewIntent()* in the Activity is equivalent to onReceive() in the Broadcast Receiver and can replace it?

Ans: No.

Q2. if not what the difference between the two?

Ans: Activity and Broadcast are two different components and these two methods are their callbacks mean when your broadcast is triggered then only you can get a callback in *onReceive()* but when your activity using singleTop launch mode and your activity is already in the top task (stack) and if your calling your same activity then only you will get a callback on onNewIntent().

Q3. Does the onNewIntent() still launch when the Activity is Paused?

Ans. This is called for activities that set launch mode to "singleTop" in their package, or if a client used the Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag when calling startActivity(Intent). In either case, when the activity is re-launched while at the top of the activity stack instead of a new instance of the activity being started, onNewIntent() will be called on the existing instance with the Intent that was used to re-launch it.

An activity can never receive a new intent in the resumed state. You can count on onResume() being called after this method, though not necessarily immediately after the completion of this callback. If the activity was resumed, it will be paused and new intent will be delivered, followed by onResume(). If the activity wasn't in the resumed state, then new intent can be delivered immediately, with onResume() called sometime later when the activity becomes active again.

Note that getIntent() still returns the original Intent. You can use setIntent(Intent) to update it to this new Intent.

***NOTE: If you don't know about launch mode and task please go through this*** link:https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.